# Open Port 25 for Message Receipt Only in Postfix

Tags: email, postfix, smtp

I have configured Postfix as an SMTP server, running on a non-standard port, using TLS, with relay.

However, I want to add the ability to receive mail directly to the user accounts on the system, and for that I have to open Port 25. But, I don't want to allow for relay to other mail servers through Port 25. Can I configure Postfix in this way, and if so, how?

Comment: Postfix doesn't relay out of the box.

Comment: Exactly what did you do?

Comment: It looks like you already have it mostly right, but I'd reject instead of defer unauthorized relaying.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Actually, I realized I probably should just `reject` outright, since I don't want to allow anything unauthenticated or outside of my network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have configured my system to allow SMTP Relay through the non-standard port, but only allow SMTP delivery on Port 25.

Remember that the `main.cf` configuration file contains the global configuration options, which the values in the `master.cf` configuration file can override.

First, I have to ensure that I've added the hosts for my server to handle to the `mydestination` variable, which I can do in `main.cf`.

Once my server knows which domains it should handle, then I have to specify slightly different options for the `smtp` (defaults to Port 25) and `smtps` (Port 465) services in `master.cf`.

Assume that `main.cf` contains the following configuration:

```
relayhost = relayhost.example.com
mydestination = local.example.com
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
```

Then, I will want to adjust the `smtp` service section in `master.cf`:

```
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
    -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=no
    -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=reject_unauth_destination
```

This kills the authentication, but only allows delivery to the `mydestination` hosts for the `smtp` service.

Comment: [A Unix.SE post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/145519/13308) helped me greatly in arriving at my solution.